# How to convert String to Double correctly?

Tags: flutter

I have read many questions on stackoverflow and didn't get what I want. I have a String with value: "1.000,00" and I want to make it a double and look exactly like this "1000.0" but I can't do it right. Using the code below, I just get "1.0" and this is incorrect. How to do this in the right way? I am using Flutter.

```
String t = "1.000,00";
double f = NumberFormat().parse(t);

userIncome = f;
```

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: Your number is culture-sensitive, causing a mistranslation.  What country are you in?

Comment: @ernest_k is Flutter.

Comment: @Summer Brazil.

Comment: @Acorcdev I think you meant Dart, right? Flutter is just a framework

Comment: Probably `DecimalFormat` would be more appropriate than `NumberFormat` if you want to customize decimal and grouping separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, is not just a "number", is a currency.

A simple way to deal with it is to convert into a number and parse:

```java
String t = "1.000,00";
// the order of replaces here is important
String formated = t.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");

userIncome = Double.valueOf(formated);
```

But, if your application is focus on currency you should take a look in this:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-money-and-currency

Comment: Dealing with the locale as @Midhun mentioned is probably more appropriate though

Comment: Yeah, currency approach is based on Locale.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the [defaultLocale](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/Intl/defaultLocale.html) property.

```dart
Intl.defaultLocale = 'pt_BR';
String t = "1.000,00";
double f = NumberFormat().parse(t);
print(f); // Prints 1000.0
```